# How do I create a bar plot with this information?

Tags: r

I have been attempting this for a while now and can't find any appropriate information, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images . Kindly refer to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(plotly)

barplot <- plot_ly(
data = data,
  x = ~weight.Category,
  y = ~Percent.of.Adults,
  name = "bar plot",
  type = "bar"
)

barplot
```